# Extra character at end while copying?

Tags: c, copying

This is making me nuts I am trying to make a simple program to copy any type of file using the following code but the result I get is unexpected (one or two extra characters at the end of copied file?). For instance if my original file has `This is an example` the copied file contains `This is an exampleÿ`

**CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp,*fpp;
    char pbuff, fname[32];
    int i;

    printf(" FILE NAME TO OPEN : ");
    scanf(" %32s", fname);
    fp = fopen(fname, "rb");
    fpp = fopen("file", "wb");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("NO SUCH FILE. EXITING NOW.");
        getch();
        exit(1);
    }

    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        pbuff = fgetc(fp);
        fputc(pbuff, fpp);
    }

    printf("SUCCESSFULLY CREATED!");
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fpp);
    getch();
    return(0);
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this one? I will be really very thankful.

Comment: feof() inside while loop can create problem , don't use it , use fgets().

Comment: could you be more specific?

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Yup 'while(!feof(fp))' from the title :(

Comment: 0)  `" %32s"` --> `" %31s"` 1) `int ch;while(EOF!=(ch = fgetc(fp)))fputc(ch, fpp);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Yoda conditions are just ugly and confusing to read any halfway recent compiler will warn about false assignment.

Comment: @Olaf I don't think so.

Comment: Op remimds me of a song/album called naveed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `feof` (like most end-of-file indicators in most languages/environments) is only set AFTER the end-of-file has been reached. Since you write the character and only then check the EOF status, you're writing 1 too many characters. `fgetc`'s return value is a predefined EOF if the end-of-file was reached during the call.

You could solve that in 1 of 2 ways:

```
while(true)
{
    pbuff = fgetc(fp);
    if(feof(fp))
         break;
    fputc(pbuff, fpp);
}
```

Or: (edit as melpomene correctly noticed!)

```
// Change pbuff to type int in the declartion, and then...
while(true)
{
    pbuff = fgetc(fp);
    if(EOF == pbuff)
         break;
    fputc(pbuff, fpp);
}
```

Comment: `pbuff` can't be a `char`, though. It has to be an `int`.

Comment: I could buy you a beer! ;)